# Why do I need to call .First() in a foreach/Select() in Json.Net?

Tags: c#, json.net

I apologize for the possibly stupid question, but...

I have the following JSON *(simplified, obviously)*:

```
{
   "rgDescriptions":{
      "32895951_0":{
         "id":"32895951",
         "name":"Cat",
      },
      "61694787_0":{
         "id":"61694787",
         "name":"Dog",
      }
   }
}
```

As a simple example of my problem, this works:

```
jsonObject["rgDescriptions"]["32895951_0"]["name"]
```

But this does not:

```
jsonObject["rgDescriptions"].First()["name"]
//InvalidOperationException:  Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.
```

In order to get it to work, I need to change it to this:

```
jsonObject["rgDescriptions"].First().First()["name"]
```

That makes no sense to me, since the first object in `jsonObject["rgDescriptions"]` should be equivalent to `["32895951_0"]`.  Both the `[]` operator and `.First()` return a JToken, so I really don't understand why `["rgDescriptions"].First()` doesn't work, or what it's really supposed to represent.

Could anyone explain to me what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it might be helpful to review what a `JToken` is and what it can contain.

- `JToken` is the abstract base class for `JObject`, `JProperty`, `JArray` and `JValue`.  These all represent the constructs that can appear in JSON.
- A `JObject` is a collection of `JProperty` objects.  It can't contain anything else.
- A `JProperty` is essentially a key-value pair.  It has a `Name` which is a string, and a `Value` which is another `JToken` that is not a `JProperty`.

With this in mind, we can answer the question.

`JObject["key"]` finds the `JProperty` in the `JObject` with the given key and returns the `JToken` which is the `Value` part of the `JProperty` (or null if the key is not found).

`JToken.First` returns the first child of the given `JToken`.  For a `JObject`, the first child is a `JProperty` (not the `Value` of the `JProperty`).  For a `JProperty`, the first (and only) child is the `Value` of the `JProperty`.

Why don't they work the same?

Well, if the `JObject["key"]` method returned a `JProperty` rather than its value, then you wouldn't be able to do  `jsonObject["key1"]["key2"]["key3"]`.  Instead, you'd have to use the more cumbersome syntax `jsonObject["key1"].Value["key2"].Value["key3"]`.

Conversely, if `JToken.First` always returned the `Value` of a `JProperty`, then you'd never be able use it to discover the `Name` of the `JProperty`.  (If you're using this method, presumably you don't already know the property's name, whereas, if you are using the other method, you do know it.)  Also, navigation properties such as `Next`, `Prev`, etc. would not work correctly because you would be at the wrong level in the heirarchy.

Comment: I'm not using `JToken.First`, I'm calling `IEnumerable.First()` - that is, it's the same as the first element in a `foreach` loop.  In that case, I'd have no reason to call `Next`, `Prev`, etc.

Comment: The answer is the same.  `IEnumerable` will enumerate the children of the `JToken`.  The children of a `JObject` are `JProperty` objects.  The child of the `JProperty` is its `Value`.